# Uploading photos to a Facebook Page as the Page itself, programmatically in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, image-uploading

## Background

I'm having a bit of trouble finding out just how to programmatically post photos to a [**Facebook Page**](https://www.facebook.com/FacebookPages). I've read through the [Facebook Documentation on Authenticating as a Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/), but [all the examples involve Facebook Users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/). So far I've just generated the needed access tokens manually using Facebook's [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/). <sub>(3)</sub>

## What I've tried

Using this simple code, I was successful in uploading the picture, however it was posted on my **own** wall, in my **own** album under my **own** name, not the on the **Facebook Page**, in the **Facebook Page**'s album under the **Facebook Page**'s name. I need to post it on a specific **Facebook Page** as the **Facebook Page** itself. <sub>(1)</sub>

```
<?php
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';
require 'config.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $config['facebook_appId'],
    'secret' => $config['facebook_appSecret'],
    'fileUpload' => true
));

$facebook->setAccessToken($config['facebook_pageAccessToken']);

$args = array(
    'message' => 'Facebook API test',
    'source' => '@'.realpath(__DIR__.'/404.jpg')
);

$data = $facebook->api('/'.$config['facebook_pageId'].'/photos', 'post', $args);
```

## About the code

- `$config['facebook_appId']` is from a dummy test app I created
- `$config['facebook_appSecret']` is from a dummy test app I created
- `$config['facebook_pageAccessToken']` is generated from the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) using the scope `manage_pages`, `publish_stream`, `photo_upload` and `offline_access` <sub>(3)</sub>

  - **As a side note to potential future visitors, it turns out I generated a User Access Token instead of a Page Access Token, which is the reason it was posted on my own wall, in my own album as myself.**
- `$config['facebook_pageId']` is the ID of the page (which I also found using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer))
- Upon successful completion `$data` contains the ID of the image and the wall post(?) it seems

## Question summary

1. **How can I post photos to a Facebook Page as the Facebook Page itself?**
2. This is for a project where developers are coming and going. Is there a way for me to have an **immutable** Page Access Token independent of a specific Facebook User **OR** dependent on a (dummy) Facebook App **OR** generating one on the fly somehow?
3. **How can I (if necessary) authenticate as a Facebook Page - giving me a Page Access Token, programmatically in PHP?**

Code examples or links to **concise** documentation and/or tutorials preferably with examples will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to all three is:

- Get the user, who is an admin of the page, to grant your app `manage_pages` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)
- If you did this client-side (i.e Javascript SDK), you'll want to extend their access token using the instructions for **Scenario 4** on https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/
- Retrieve the `access_token` for the page via a call to `/me/permissions` or a call to `/[PAGE_ID]/?fields=access_token`. If you extended the page admin's access_token before retrieving the page access token, the page access token will not expire unless the user stops being an admin of the page or changes their password, revokes permission to the app, etc (Scenario 5 on the doc above)
- Use that access token to upload the photo to the page's wall.

I think most of these steps are clarified here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/ (logging in as the page) or in this the [Page documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)

Comment: Great answer, will look into the links. However, is there a way for a Facebook Page to grant a Facebook App the required privileges? I'm still eager on doing minimum work when it comes to making sure the App has the needed access independently of who is the owner of the Facebook Page itself.

Comment: A 'page' doesn't grant anything in and of itself, one of the admins of that page grants your app the permission, and then you obtain an `access_token` to act on behalf of the page; effectively this is the same thing, one of the admins will always have to delegate their control of the page to your app

Comment: Sorry, unclear formulation by me, I meant: Is there a way for a Page Admin to grant a Facebook App `photo_upload` and `publish_stream` on a Facebook Page, without the Facebook App losing these privileges when the Page Admin is removed (replaced)? Or do ALL photo album management have to be done through a Facebook User (which is non-constant)? In my mind this seems to encourage making fake accounts (however probably not allowed in the TOS), then give them admin rights on the page, and use them to create the Page Access Token. Can I perhaps use test users to achieve this? Appreciate your time.

Comment: All pages have admins, those admins grant access to apps to act on their behalf as an admin, including impersonating (i.e posting as) the page - if that page admin is removed, you'll need one of the other admins to authorise your app - this is intentional and there's no workarounds that don't involve (as you said) using fake admins of the page, but i don't understand why that's any different to using real admins for your purposes

Comment: I think you're vastly overestimating how often a page's admins change